# Multiple LIKE statement using AND in Sqlite.

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to select recipe_id for recipes that have my both ingredient but I cant use AND like this(I mean it returns null for all columns) :

```
SELECT
   vsearch.ingredient_id,
   vsearch.ingredtypes_id,
   vsearch.name,
   vsearch.recipe_id,
   vsearch.qingred
FROM
   vsearch
WHERE
   vsearch.name = 'olive' AND vsearch.name = 'apple'
```

vsearch is a View which is:

```
SELECT 
   ingredient.ingredient_id,
   ingredient.ingredtypes_id,
   ingredient.name,
   quantity.recipe_id,
   quantity.ingredient_id AS qingred
FROM
   ingredient ,
   quantity
WHERE
   strong textingredient.ingredient_id = quantity.ingredient_id
```

And heres my database tables:[image]

Comment: Doesnt your statement `vsearch.name = 'olive' AND vsearch.name = 'apple'` make the query/result ambigious. How can 1 item have 2 names at the same time ?

Comment: Could you add a sample of what your desired result is?

Comment: @Sagar Waghmare you know there is quantity table which contain list of ingredient which is associated to a recipe_id along with amount of that ingredient, what i want to do is Select a recipe id where both Apple and Olive have considered as ingredient to that recipe. am I Wrong? please explain more.

Answer (score 1):

To find (for example) find the recipe id's that contain both cucumber and tomato;

```
SELECT recipe_id 
FROM vsearch
WHERE name = 'cucumber' OR name = 'tomato'
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

...where 2 is the name of ingredients that have to match (in this case both)

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8b10/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from vsearch
where recipe_id
in
( select recipe_id from vsearch where name = 'apple'
  intersect
  select recipe_id from vsearch where name = 'olive'
)
```